# Converting string into array in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have string like below

```
["Day1"]["Morning"]=mutton&["Day1"]["Evening"]=Juice&["Day2"]["Morning"]=burger&["Day2"]["Evening"]=pizza
```

Which i am trying to convert into array like below

```
$arr["Day1"]["Morning"] = "mutton";
$arr["Day1"]["Evening"] = "Juice";
$arr["Day2"]["morning"] = "burger";
$arr["Day2"]["evening"] = "pizza";
```

I tried something like below.

```
$str = '["Day1"]["Morning"]=mutton&["Day1"]["Evening"]=Juice&["Day2"]["Morning"]=burger&["Day2"]["Evening"]=pizza';
$pieces = explode("&", $str);

foreach($pieces as $pie)
{
$arr.$pie;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

I know above code is really dumb :/ .Is there any proper solution for this ?

Comment: How are you getting this data? It hardly looks standard.

Comment: there are large data like this in my client database .. I am trying to clean it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do like this...

```
<?php
$str='["Day1"]["Morning"]=mutton&["Day1"]["Evening"]=Juice&["Day2"]["Morning"]=burger&["Day2"]["Evening"]=pizza';
$arr = explode('&',$str);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $valarr=explode('=',$v);
    preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $valarr[0], $matches);
    $narr[$matches[1][0]][$matches[1][1]]=$valarr[1];
}

print_r($narr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [Day1] => Array
        (
            [Morning] => mutton
            [Evening] => Juice
        )

    [Day2] => Array
        (
            [Morning] => burger
            [Evening] => pizza
        )

)
```

You could access like `echo $arr["Day1"]["Morning"]` which prints `mutton`

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/101105)

Comment: Perfect like piece of cake :D , can i know what you are doing inside loop ?

Comment: Inside the loop the elements are exploded using `=` and last element is assigned as value. whereas the first element is checked for double quote matches and they are caught up in another array `$matches`. So those values are subjected as the keys to your new array.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it could be parsed with `parse_str()`, but not without some conversion:

```
$str = '["Day1"]["Morning"]=mutton&["Day1"]["Evening"]=Juice&["Day2"]["Morning"]=burger&["Day2"]["Evening"]=pizza';

parse_str(preg_replace('/(?<=^|&)/', 'x', str_replace('"', '', $str)), $a);

var_dump($a['x']);
```

It removes the double quotes, prefixes each entry with `x` and then applies `parse_str()`. To get an idea of what the `preg_replace()` does, the intermediate result is this:

```
x[Day1][Morning]=mutton&x[Day1][Evening]=Juice&x[Day2][Morning]=burger&x[Day2][Evening]=pizza
```

Parsing the above string yields an array with a single root element `x`.

Comment: **+1** for a one-liner !

Comment: +1 for simple solution :) but sorry i accepted answer already